# Rails and Postgres aren't getting along after switching from Macports to Homebrew; PGError: ERROR: unrecognized time zone name: "UTC"

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, macports, homebrew

I moved everything that I had in `/opt/local` (where Macports' things lived) into `~/.macports`. That included my old postgres database cluster.

Then I installed postgres using Homebrew and ran the setup that it told me to (creating a new database cluster in `/usr/local`).

In my project, I ran `rake db:drop:all` and `rake db:create`. These did their work cheerfully.

But when I tried to `rake db:migrate`, postgres and rails fight and tell me

```
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  unrecognized time zone name: "UTC"
: SET time zone 'UTC'
```

I don't know what they're talking about, though. I found [this article](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5324-configtime_zone-not-setting-default_timezone-for-ar-causing-errors-with-postgres) about a `config.time_zone` bug slightly illuminating, but not enough to find my way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure how I fixed it, but uninstalling Postgres and reinstalling it (and following the setup instructions it gives very carefully) got it working.

Comment: Hi, coming across the same problem. All you did was brew uninstall postgres and then brew install postgres? And everything worked? I tried this, but the same issue is coming up

Comment: Actually the problem was with a scope I had: scope :by_recent, where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', 1.month.ago, Time.now).order('created_at desc')... Strange that this problem is happening

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error and simply need to start postgres manually:

```
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

You can also stop it:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

Answer (score 1):

After much head banging, I solved this problem by running:

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`